# Python: converting dictionaries into objects with read/write methods

Tags: python, io, samba, pysmb

I need to be able to read/write files using samba connection in Python.
For this purpose I use pysmb. However, I am cannot make storeFile function work:

```
storeFile(service_name, path, file_obj, timeout=30)
```

Where `file_obj` – A file-like object that has a read method.

Suppose I have the following dictionary: `res={1:np.ones((3,3))}`. Locally I would store it with `np.save` function. Here I tried:

```
conn.storeFile('BigDataDirectory','data_genkin/2.npz',res)
```

And got the following error:

```
`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'`
```

Can someone suggest a solution how to convert a dictionary into a file with read method. Similarly, to read a file from samba server I need an output object that has a write method.

Thanks,

Mikhail

Comment: what format should the dictionary be saved in?

Comment: sorry, I've just realised what `numpy.save()` does why not just follow the example from the docs saving to a `TemporaryFile` and then passing this to the `storeFile`?

Comment: Ah ok, I think I know the issue you mean

Comment: I honestly don't care much as long as it is binary format (efficient stream read/write). I'd prefer something similar to npz files